# NullPointerException when trying to copy/paste from/into clipboard

Tags: java, windows, swing, nullpointerexception, clipboard

I have an specific issue with copy/paste from my Java application. I made IT utility that we use in our IT Department for Evidence of our IT assessments.

When I try to copy from anything (`jTextArea`, `jTextField`, `jTable` cell, etc..) I receive bellow shown `NullPointerException`.

This issue appears randomly, I can copy In/Out all I want, but then, let say hour after, I want to copy some information out and this appears, after that I cannot copy anything in or out and only thing that helps is restarting the application. After Restart, I can try to copy anything anywhere, even use Java `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard()` function with no error, but again, after some time (usually after one or more hours) it appears again. For this time, there is only one active scheduled method that keeps refreshing the main table from SQL. I don't think that my code will help here is this application have more that 65K rows ant this issue appears randomly anywhere.

But my question is - Is there any special way to treat system Clipboard, or are there any common mistakes that could make such behavior?  I found nothing that could help me understand my problem.

I'll appreciate any help or leads whatsoever, thank you:)

Error message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Win32FileSystem.normalize(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.Win32FileSystem.getUserPath(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.Win32FileSystem.resolve(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.getAbsolutePath(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.getAbsoluteFile(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.toURI(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap.initSystemFlavorMap(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap.getFlavorToNative(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap.getNativesForFlavor(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.datatransfer.DataTransferer.getFormatsForFlavors(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WDataTransferer.getFormatsForFlavors(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.datatransfer.DataTransferer.getFormatsForTransferable(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WClipboard.setContentsNative(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.datatransfer.SunClipboard.setContents(Unknown Source)
    at GUI.Evidence.EvidenceMain.SaveToClip(EvidenceMain.java:711)
    at GUI.Evidence.EvidenceMain.access$800(EvidenceMain.java:65)
    at GUI.Evidence.EvidenceMain$4.mouseReleased(EvidenceMain.java:401)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

    java.io.IOException: cannot transfer non-text data as Reader
    at sun.awt.datatransfer.DataTransferer.translateTransferable(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WDataTransferer.translateTransferable(Unknown Source)

    at sun.awt.windows.WClipboard.setContentsNative(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.datatransfer.SunClipboard.setContents(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.TransferHandler.exportToClipboard(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.TransferHandler$TransferAction.actionPerformedImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.TransferHandler$TransferAction.access$700(Unknown Source)

    at javax.swing.TransferHandler$TransferAction$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.TransferHandler$TransferAction$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.TransferHandler$TransferAction$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.TransferHandler$TransferAction$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.TransferHandler$TransferAction.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.invokeAction(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.copy(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit$CopyAction.actionPerformed(UnknownSource)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)

    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) 
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: Seems `NPE` in `IDontThinkThatMyCodeWillHelpHere.java:711`

Comment: unfortunately I'm unable to make example to simulate where this issue occurres, as it can be triggered by copying from simple jTextField containing simple String, with even no event listeners added to it. The only thing in common for this issue is, that it is being "triggered" after some idle time of not using this application

Comment: @Alex2410 - I totally agree with you that without code that would show where does this issue appears it is nearly imposible to help. But as I said previously, I dont need to write some clipboard listener, simple CTRL + C will make it as well, without somehow trying to contact system clipboard previously.